# Crystal report displays page number as 1 of 1+

Tags: reporting-services, vb6, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-8.5

I am using crystal report 8.5 with VB6. So in some of my reports the page number is displayed as `1 of 1+` when i click on next the page number becomes `2 of 2+` and so on. When i reach last page say 8th page it becomes `8 of 8`. I dont know which setting causes this to come like this. I want page number to be displayed properly as `1 of 8` and so on. So please help me on this.

Below is a screenshot of that error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only found reason for the error and solution to it.
http://scn.sap.com/message/14609181#14609181

The rpt which does not displays page number properly(i.e displayed 1 of 1+ in viewer) had page number field used in it. But there was no field which triggers total page count. So i was getting 1 of 1+.When i reach last page it gets the page count so when i click previous page it updates page number properly in viewer.

So it can be solved by using TotalPageCount  some where in the rpt file so that it updates it at the beginning it self when displaying first page.

Comment: This answer is still valid in 2021 btw.

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell you exactly why the Report Viewer does that, but to get rid of this behavior just add from 'Special Fields' in the Field Explorer the  field 'Page N of M' anywhere in your report and change its suppress property to true. Adding this field to your report will display the number of all pages in your toolbar correctly.